# Access 2013 Custom Web App DatePart Query

Tags: ms-access-2013

I'm currently constructing a query that processes timesheets so that total hours can be viewed for a week for all employees (as well as weekly and daily breakdowns).

I'm using Microsoft Access 2013 to create a custom web app (different syntax to the desktop version)

I currently have an expression in 'week' field that looks like this:

```
DatePart(Week,[LogDate])
```

This does work.

I need the week to start on Thursday and end on Wednesday for payroll. Is there any way to do this? I've tried:

```
DatePart(Week,[LogDate],vbThursday,vbFirstFourDays)
```

but that hasn't worked. I've also tried variants like:

```
DatePart(Week,[LogDate],vbThursday)
```

And others, but I get the error message "The expression you entered has a function containing the wrong number of elements". What am I doing wrong? Or is this even possible for Web apps?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you sure `DatePart(Week,[LogDate])` works?  And why don't the other two work?   Do you get an error or something?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do get an error when I try the others. The error for the variants says "The expression you entered has a function containing the wrong number of elements".

I've edited the main post to include the error message.